# Wordpress "the upload file not be moved wp-content upload"

Tags: wordpress, vagrant, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

Oi guys i've this problem...
When i try to upload a new theme or image go out this error

```
The uploaded file could not be moved to wp-content/uploads.
```

I do `sudo chmod 777 -R wordpress.` 
But nothing.

I use vagrant with ubuntu/trusty64

Thanks Guys, Greetings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix it!

Vagrant virtualize with VirtualBox or other.
you do the permission of the directory in your base System and the vagrant
emulate system.

Have a nice days guys !

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your chmod command it should be `sudo chmod -R 777 wordpress`, the -R should be before the 777. Not sure if that was just a typo but it's the only thing I can think of now just looking at your question.

Edit:

I looked up on wordpress stack exchange and found a potential answer. You might need to specifically define the upload directory. see this [page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/161123/cant-upload-media-permissions-are-correct)

Answer (score 0):

See it:

```
  root@davide:/var/www/html/wordpress# ls -l
        total 168
        -rwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant   418 Sep 25  2013 index.php
        -rwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant 19935 Jan  2 18:51 license.txt
        -rwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant  7433 Jan 11 17:46 readme.html
        -rwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant  5447 Sep 27 21:36 wp-activate.php
        drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant  3060 Feb 21 20:09 wp-admin
        -rwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant   364 Dec 19  2015 wp-blog-header.php
        -rwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant  1627 Aug 29 12:00 wp-comments-post.php
        -rwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant  2832 Feb 21 20:09 wp-config.php
        drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant   238 Feb 21 20:12 wp-content
        -rwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant  3286 May 24  2015 wp-cron.php
        drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant  6392 Feb 21 20:09 wp-includes
        -rwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant  2422 Nov 21 02:46 wp-links-opml.php
        -rwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant  3301 Oct 25 03:15 wp-load.php
        -rwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant 33939 Nov 21 02:46 wp-login.php
        -rwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant  8048 Jan 11 05:15 wp-mail.php
        -rwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant 16250 Nov 29 05:39 wp-settings.php
        -rwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant 29896 Oct 19 04:47 wp-signup.php
        -rwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant  4513 Oct 14 19:39 wp-trackback.php
        -rwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant  3065 Aug 31 16:31 xmlrpc.php
```

Nothing the problem it isn't solved